# Grouping Files in Project Explorer in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, winavr, logical-grouping

I am newbie to Eclipse, I am planning to use it for AVR development with WinAVR and gcc.
The feature I am looking for is the grouping of different files in the project, like all headers together, all source files together and all files excluded from the build together etc.

I tried AVR Studio from Atmel, it has this grouping feature but it lacks several other features which Eclipse supports. Any help to configure Eclipse Project explorer to display the project files in this way would be appreciated and helpful for me to decide the IDE to use.

Note: I know that I can manually add different folders for each of these groups and move the files, but that moves the physical files, and breaks the relative path in the code, and other comilers/IDE's. I am looking for logical grouping of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no general way for a user to configure the grouping in the Project Explorer, the grouping is setup based on the code that controls the content (i.e. CDT, JDT, etc).  I think it would be interesting to have this feature, but it's not clear the UI that can be used to specify it.  You are welcome to submit an enhancement request to add this to the Eclipse Platform UI project.  And giving an example of how it's done in another product would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Francis, looking at your profile I think I found the right person to solve my issue :)
I have opened it as a bug (as I could not find a feature request in bugzila) [Bug 296514](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=296514) - Logical Grouping Files in Project Explorer in Eclipse

I have attcahed screenshots of both AVR Studio and Eclipse project explorer. That should give you an idea of what kind of UI features I am requesting. I can difinetely provide more information if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for can be done with Working Sets.